# How to change the WindowManager.LayoutParams' type programmatically?

Tags: android, lockscreen, android-windowmanager

I got a view that I am able to display on the lockscreen. But I want it to make it optional. Currently I use these params to achieve this:

```
WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ERROR, 
WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED |
WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE | 
WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH | 
WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS, PixelFormat.TRANSPARENT);
```

And for not showing it on the lockscreen I use

```
WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE, 
WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE | 
WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH | 
WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS, PixelFormat.TRANSPARENT);
```

Separately they work fine, but I want to change the type and flags programmatically. So I tried changing the WindowManager.LayoutParams with

```
params.flags &= ~WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ERROR;
params.flags &= ~WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED;
params.flags |= WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE;
windowManager.updateViewLayout(myView,params);
```

to remove the type, remove  the flag and set a new type,
but that doesn't seem to work. Does anyone know how to do this correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are setting `type` values into `flag`. Try this instead:

```java
params.flags &= ~WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED;

// type is no bit flag, so this should do it
params.type = WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE;
```